# how to clear whatsapp data or chat in android?

Tags: android

i want to clear whatsapp data or all chat in app .

whatsapp delete all chat from whatsapp setting without need to root . but i want to delete data/data/com.whatsapp  need to root .

```
File dir = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/data/com.whatsapp");
    deleteFolder(dir);
```

or

```
File dir = new File("/data/data/com.whatsapp");
    deleteFolder(dir);
```

if clear data is possible without root explain that Otherwise explain that way with root .

Comment: Just open the app info and click `Clear data`

Comment: ONLY the app can access/modify its own data , so whatsapp clears its own data without root, `/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME` is created for each app. only the app can access that path, unless ROOT is granted

Comment: Pedro , i want clear code.

Comment: Yazan , haven't any way to clear data ?

Comment: Well that would be the worse. Think of it this way. If every app could access other app's data would you be cool about it?

Comment: that wouldn't be so cool

Comment: (PedroOliveira +1)... @Eli, as far as i know no root, no access, imagine an app that deletes or reads /data/data/* what would be the situation then :)